# Filament curls up in the nozzle and doesn't stick to the bed

Tags: troubleshooting, adhesion, anet-a8

We have an old Anet A8 3D printer. It took us a while to fix it and get it running. But when it prints, the filament curls up and sticks to the nozzle end and doesn't stick to the bed.

Sometimes it doesn't curl up, if I wipe the nozzle after the printer starts. But when it prints, a portion of the filament sticks to the bed, but as the head moves, the whole thread of the filament dries up quickly and drags the part that did stick with it, messing everything up and curling up the nozzle like the first case.

My Anet A8 has a heated bed, but although the bed heats up, it seems like the filament dries up too quickly. Is that the problem, how to fix it ?

Comment: What material are you printing? What is your hotend and bed temperature?

Comment: This is some 4 years old ABS I think. Can it cause problems? I print at 215 C and 60 C.

Comment: This is pretty low for ABS. You should try printing with higher temperatures, more appropriate for ABS. Don't you have a spool or few grams of PLA to test just bed adhesion and exclude problems with the printer?

Comment: It it looks like it was problem with temperature. It prints now good on 260C I also printed some PLA scraps and it sticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is a problem with temperature. After changing filament temperature to 260 °C it prints excellent now. Printing PLA at 215 °C also works pretty well. Fresh new spool does magic or PLA does magic.